# How to click on a webpage element with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[Imgur Web Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M06Fy.jpg)

I want to write a line of code that clicks on the ellipsis on the webpage. I've attached the element description.

I can't share the webpage as it is password protected

Here's what I tried:

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.fas.fa-ellipsis-v')
element.click()

I am expecting the ellipsis to pop open but i get the following error:

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".fas.fa-ellipsis-v"}

Comment: Maybe there are multiple elements that have this class, so the selector would return the first in the DOM, which might not be the one you're looking for? Hard to tell if you can't provide a [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps the element is loaded by JavaScript after the initial page load. Try initializing the driver with `driver.implicitly_wait(3)` (or some other time value). This will allow the call to `find_element_by_css_selector` wait for up to 3 seconds for the sought element to appear on the page. Maybe you can't share the page, but you could have shared your code.

Comment: If you run `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.fas.fa-ellipsis-v')` (notice elements instead of element) you get a list with how many elements?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please, do not use images when your want a code review or help, it is more easier to help with raw code.

In that case:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".fas.fa-ellipsis-v"}
```

Try to use this code below instead of `driver.find_element_by_css_selector([...])` :

```
WebDriverWait(your_driver, your_timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, your_locator)))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(your_driver, your_timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, your_locator)))
```

After the WaitDriverWait, use your find and click code.

If you need more help locating elements by, try look the [Selenium Docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#locate-elements-by).

Comment: It turns out there's two ellipsis elements. I can get the code to click on the first one, but not the second one. Here's what I last tried:

# Find all elements with the class "fas fa-ellipsis-v"
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fas fa-ellipsis-v")
# Click on the second element
elements[1].click()

Here's the error message: 
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Verify if the page contains iframe tag. If contains, first select frame and try to click.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by using the following line:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```